# D3 define line based on previous element in data array

Tags: d3.js

With D3 (v4), is there a way to define my line so that a value has to equal the previous value. In other words, if a grouping variable changes, can I not draw this part of the line? I know the following doesn't work, but something like...

```
var line = d3.line().defined(function(d,i) { return d.year === d[i-1].year; })
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. You have to reference the actual data variable in the defined function AND you have to provide some logic to skip the first index, like so:

```
var line = d3.line().defined(function(d,i) {
  if(i>0) {
       return d.year === data[i-1].year;
    } else {
       return d.year === d.year;
    }
}
```